# Problemas con Mysql en Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, xampp

Tengo instalado mysql con el xampp y tambien lo tengo instalado por aparte,NO quiero trabajar con el mysql del xampp, como hago para poder trabajar con el otro mysql y no con el del xampp, si no estoy mal debo configurar los puertos para poder hacer lo que quiero, pero no se como configurarlo... y por eso no arranca el mysql del xampp... me interesa mas que arranque el otro mysql, y no el mysql del xampp... como lo haria? presento el siguiente aviso:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

> SOLUCION

se estaba presentando un conflicto con los puertos, es decir mysql del xampp corria en el puerto 3306, y como tengo instalado el otro mysql por aparte que tambien corria por el mismo puerto lo que hice fue cambiar el puerto del mysql del xampp y lo puese en el puerto 3307 y funciono!

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que es un error relacionado a permisos y todo ese rollo, escribe esto en la terminal para cambiar los permisos actuales que tienes:

```
chmod 644 /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf
```

**PD:** *Por experiencia personal te sugiero que uses LAMP y no XAMPP, por si gustas cambiarte [sigue este tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04), en realidad es muy sencillo, saludos :)*

Comment: gracias... pero me refiero a la linea donde dice tuberia rota.